# Google one-tap sign in error: "unregistered_origin"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-one-tap

I have implemented Google One-Tap Sign In on my site, and it works fine on localhost.

However, when testing it on my any other device on the network I get the following error message:

`unregistered_origin`

What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I haven't used the one-tap API, but the error sounds like an issue with CORS. In particular, you may not be authorizing your origin in the google-one-tap API. See [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid)

Comment: @Dshiz Please, if possible, post a bunch of potential solutions or whatever so that I can sift through it all.

Remember that this error does to appear when using localhost, only when using another device on the same network.

I do not yet know if this error appears if the site is Live.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the url you are coming from to the "Authorized Javascript origins" in "Web Client" here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/credentials

Also, as a heads up, Google doesn't allow schemes other than `localhost` or `a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).`